# Cygwin Folder too large, taking up 10gb?? Is there a way to reduce this without reinstalling?

Tags: cygwin, size, storage

Title. My Cygwin folder is absolutely huge meanwhile I've seen answers here that say Cygwin is only supposed to be 100-250 mb. Mine is 10gb!! I've already tried deleting tmp, but it didn't work.

Comment: I assume that you have too many packages installed. What is output of `cygcheck -cd | wc -l` ?

Comment: Use the `du` command to discover where disk space is used; add `--help` to show usage. Use `du  -h --max-depth=1 -x /` to show the sizes of top level directories; change max-depth or the directory to drill deeper. Use `du  -b -x / | sort -n | tail -20` to show the 20 largest directories; add `-all` to also show largest files. Note: you *must* use the `-x` option, or you will include all your windows drives. Note that one does not usually install all cygwin packages. Normally, we do the initial setup, and then install only the packages (and their dependencies) that we use. - HTH

Comment: @matzeri it outputs 2247

Comment: than 10 GB is normal. To reduce size you need to remove packages that you do not use. The setup allows to uninstall packages